# Bootstrap Datepicker Customization

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I m using bootstrap datepicker here is the javascript of this.

```
    initDashboardDaterange: function () {
                $('#dashboard-report-range').daterangepicker({
                        opens: (Metronic.isRTL() ? 'right' : 'left'),
                        startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
                        endDate: moment(),
                        minDate: '01/01/2012',
                        maxDate: '12/31/2014',
                        dateLimit: {
                            days: 60
                        },
                        showDropdowns: false,
                        showWeekNumbers: true,
                        timePicker: true,
                        timePickerIncrement: 1,
                        timePicker12Hour: true,
                        ranges: {
     \\I added this         'Live': [''],
     \\I added this         'Last 10 Minutes': [moment().set('minute', 10)],
     \\I added this         'Last Hour': [moment().startOf('hour')],
                            'Today': [moment()],
                            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'),   moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                        },
                        buttonClasses: ['btn btn-sm'],
                        applyClass: ' blue',
                        cancelClass: 'default',
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        separator: ' to ',
                        locale: {
                            applyLabel: 'Apply',
                            fromLabel: 'From',
                            toLabel: 'To',
                            customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
                            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                            firstDay: 1
                       }
                    },
//this function show the selected date range in the div
                    function (start, end) {
                        $('#dashboard-report-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));    //this is the place i have to edit it..
                    }
                );
                $('#dashboard-report-range span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                $('#dashboard-report-range').show();
            },    };
```

**Now when I am adding more values it is just accepting the dates not other thing if I just want to display the selected value there like I click on Live, Last 10 Minutes or Last Hour it will just display live, Last 10 minutes or Last hour respectively. I have tried to add there but it is giving me errors..**

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors you're getting. I've never used moment and  this date-picker but the lines you've added differ from the existing lines in that you pass an array with a single value while they all have 2 values in the array.

Comment: yes it is picking 2 values it is actually a daterange from date A to Date B.. They are working fine but now I am adding 3 more options Live, Last Hour and Last 10 minutes. The function need two values but I m looking for something like when I will click on Live it will just display Live word written on the box not date range for these new added options.. The errors are ofcourse invalid date format and it is highlighting multiple values..

Comment: I think it can't be done with the datepicker you're using, but it's worthwhile to wait and see if someone else can help.